# Persistent Session with passportjs + sails.js Implementation

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Can anyone point me to a link or explain how to implement persistent sessions with passportjs in sails.js. I know it involves connect-mongo but was not really familiar on how to implement it. Session gets destroyed every time nodejs restarts.

Please shed some light.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to install connect-mongo
`npm install connect-mongo --save` then uncomment the **adapter**, **host**, **port**, **db** and **collection** objects on your config/session.js.

That's all mate!

Answer (score 0):

The configuration to change is in the file `config/session.js`.

Basically you can change the *adapter* property for either `mongo` or `redis` and provide a connection URL.

There is more explanations here: http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Configuration/Session.html

P.S: In fact, using Passportjs or not as little to do with how the session is stored by Sails

Comment: Does it have other approach not involving databases or is it the only possible way to achieve persistent session storage in sails?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure I'm following you. Even outside Sailsjs, there isn't 100 ways to achieve persistent sessions. But Sails doesn't support stateless sessions (Fully client side) by default if that's what you mean.

Comment: What I was really trying to achieve here is to keep the data in sessions even when sailsJS is restarted. it's a bit of a pain when you are developing and you keep on logging in every time you restart sails.